# Changing Textbox FontFamily does not take effect in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I need to use a font family in my application. I added the following snippet in App.Resources

```
 <FontFamily x:Key="SourceSanProFontFamily">Assets/Fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf#Source Sans Pro</FontFamily>
```

And i applied fontfamily to the textblock.

```
 <TextBlock  Text="Welcomeg!"   FontFamily="{StaticResource SourceSanProFontFamily}"></TextBlock>
```

When application is not running,it is fine and i can see the change. But when I running the application it doest not take effect.

Why this happens? How to resolve this?

Comment: I've just tried a sample example - new app with your code and it seems that it's running on both emulator and device. I've downloaded font from [here](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-sans-pro/archive/2.010R-ro/1.065R-it.zip).

Comment: @Romasz yes i added .ttf file to the solution and i used it. But it doesn't take effect when it is running.

Comment: Can you try to run [this example from github](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/FontExampleSourceSansPro), just put there the font from the link from first comment.

Comment: @Romasz Yes. Your sample is the working one with the same code i have chosen.And i figured out that we need a '/' before the font path when we declaring it in any other resource dictionaries. And it works now .Thank you very much for your help. If you put it as answer, I can mark it as answered. :)

Comment: I've added the answer, please correct if there is something missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our combined forces managed to solve the problem - after checking [the working sample project](https://github.com/Romasz/WP81RunTime-Examples/tree/master/FontExampleSourceSansPro) it turend out that when the *FontFamily* is declared in other *ResourceDictionaries* additional `/` is needed:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="SourceSanProFontFamily">/Assets/Fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf#Source Sans Pro</FontFamily>
```